# How do I resolve Cannot create a DbSet for 'CUserMasterLocal' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to keep my application and identity handling on their own separate contexts, but I am running up against the error message

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'CUserMasterLocal' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

From my online research it appears that I need to have `ApplicationDBContext` inherit from `IdentityDbContext` rater than `DBContext`, but as stated, I want to have to have identity management in its own context. At least one Stack Overflow post tells me this is not allowed, has any of the community managed to keep identity in a its own context?

This is my Identity context:

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CUserMasterLocal, CRoleMasterLocal, string>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Customizations must go after base.OnModelCreating(builder)

        var x = builder.Entity<CUserMasterLocal>(config =>
        {
            // Set the default table name of AspNetUsers
            config.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        });


        builder.Entity<CRoleMasterLocal>(config =>
        {
            config.ToTable("RoleMaster");
        });
    }
    public DbSet<CUserMasterLocal> UserMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CRoleMasterLocal> RoleMaster { get; set; }
}
```

In startup.cs I have

```
var identityConnectionString = this.Configuration["Data:VT_LocalIdentityData:ConnectionString"];
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(identityConnectionString));
services.AddIdentity<CUserMasterLocal, CRoleMasterLocal>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Within my controller, I have isolated the identity activity via a 'block'

```
using (var localIdContext = new AppIdentityDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
    CUserMasterLocal userMaster = CreateUserMasterEntry(person, 
        userDetails.GetUsername());

    IdentityResult result = this.userManager.CreateAsync(userMaster, 
        GeneratePassword(12)).Result;
}
```

For the avoidance of doubt, `CUserMasterLocal` is not referenced in the class that sets up `ApplicationDBContext`, and I would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're registering your Identity services did you mean to have `ApplicationDbContext` as your EntityFrameworkStores?

Try replacing

```cs
services.AddIdentity<CUserMasterLocal, CRoleMasterLocal>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() // <--- this doesn't seem right.
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

with

```cs
services.AddIdentity<CUserMasterLocal, CRoleMasterLocal>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>() // <--- this is changed
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```